# To what state would copper wiring revert if abandoned for centuries?

Tags: oxidation-state

Would copper wires from power transmission or telephone lines acquire a patina but remain largely intact, or oxidize into dust after a century or more without replacement or maintenance?

Obviously environmental factors would be enormous; ideally I'd like to know what the metal's state would be in ideal (underground?), typical (temperate zone), and worst-case (near salt water?) scenarios. Clearly some circumstances allow copper objects to survive largely intact for several thousand years, since such artifacts have been found by archeologists, but does this require very exceptional circumstances?

This question is inspired by an answer on the Worldbuilding site, which claims that a post-apocalyptic society would have a difficult time developing metallurgy as the rusted remains of human civilization would be *more* difficult to smelt than the naturally-occurring ores which were relatively abundant during the Stone Age. Hopefully by asking about this copper wires specifically, I have an appropriate question for this site. If so, I may ask another question about iron and steel.

I did not have much luck in finding relevant tags. Any assistance there is appreciated!

Comment: Copper sheathing for roofs can last a very long time, indeed acquiring a nice patina.  It might not be a great roof after a century, but it will still be there.

Comment: True. The Clarksville Customs House is over 100 years old, and the roof has survived tornadoes. However, copper wiring is presumably much more widespread. Though I understand that most power lines are largely aluminum these days.

Answer (score 2):

Let me talk first about how iron corrodes (as in rusts) and then compare that to copper. The simple answer is that when iron corrodes, the iron oxide (iron which has chemically bonded with oxygen, which it loves to do) that forms on the surface of the pure iron underneath, does not seal the surface against further intrusion of more oxygen. When copper corrodes, the copper oxide does seal the surface protecting underlying copper against further corrosion. I don't know if iron oxide is simply more porous to oxygen than copper oxide is but I do know the following. Iron can chemically combine with oxygen in multiple ratios. When you examine a highly corroded iron surface you'll notice that the first layer of rust is very red. If you brush or maybe lightly sand that red layer of rust away you'll notice a black layer underneath it. That's still rust. If you sand your way through that you'll get to the pure iron underneath which has more of a dark silver color. The red rust has more oxygen in it than the black rust but can pass some of that oxygen to the black rust turning it red. Similarly, the black rust can pass some of its oxygen on to the pure iron underneath it. That process continues until oxygen can leach all the way through the iron. Chemically, iron has more than one oxidation state. Oxidized copper atoms are much more reluctant to release their oxygen to adjacent pure copper and act as a barrier to the intrusion of more oxygen.

Comment: Right, iron is notorious that way. I heard that it's because the oxide has a greater volume, and thus the outer layer expands and separates from the inner layer, exposing it. Regarding copper, though, will the layer of oxide protect the inner part indefinitely, as long as there is no mechanical action to expose fresh metal? Will it survive for years, decades, centuries? What if it's exposed to rain, or standing water?